# cordova google map does not working for android

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps

I am a beginner of Cordova.   I am trying to display the google map in the android emulator.

So first I include the android plug in like this.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="ANDROID_API_KEY"
```

And I called google map code.     But the google map did not appear.

Only said this alert.

> xx won't run unless you update Google Play services.

I read lots of tutorials and sample codes. But another code did not run.   I think this depend on the config xml.

In the config file I did not any tag.

Lots of tutorials recommend to add "`<access origin="*" />`". But this tag is default tag.

Of course I add android google service sdk.   I develop the anroid google app using android studio. It works well. It means all google sdk are already installed.   But I am not sure cordova needs another sdk.

Anyway please help me which one is wrong.  I can show lots of sample codes. But nothing works.

Please help me.

Comment: Depends on which targetsdk your android studio is using and your cordova project is using,Check AndroidManifest.xml of working project and try setting the same targetsdk in cordova AndroidManifest.xml under platforms

Comment: Thanks.  I think if I modify the config.xml, then it will affect to the manifest.xml file.   So should I change the manifest.xml after build the code.?

Comment: you should modify AndroidManifest.xml before building the code